# Change the name of network interface under Linux, but the file 70-persistent-net.rules ignored

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I used Promox to create a virtual machine and added a new network interface. The virtual machine is running Ubuntu 12.04. When I did the ifconfig I have two interface: eth0 and eth1.
Now I modified the 70-persistent-net.rules in /etc/udev/rules.d and want to change the name of network interface, i.e. change eth1 to net_c
But when I restarted the machine, the system seems ignored this file and didn't do the rename configuration

Can anyone tell me what is the problem?

Comment: I too run 12.04, and had problems with udev rules being ignored (or overruled). The details are in my askUbuntu [question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/399263/udev-rules-seem-ignored-can-not-prevent-modem-manager-from-grabbing-device), but the gist is I ended up editing my Network Manager conf when udev failed. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to override rules with you own personal rule in /etc/udev/rules.d, you must have a number higher than the rules in /lib/udev/rules.d that you want to override.
In /lib/udev/rules.d, persistent net are in "75-persistent-net-generator.rules", so name your rules with a number higher than 75 :)